# Error: Login session requires session support . Did you forget to use `express-session` middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, passport.js

Image 1

[image: 1]

Image 2

[image: 2]

Expect: No errors for it (is it the order wrong or what) i didnt get error last year and soon i quit coding and now im back in coding it shows error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **express-session** before using **passport.session**

**npm install express-session**

```
var session = require('express-session')

app.use(session({
  //
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Answer (score -1):

use {session:false} in authentication callback i.e. passport.authenticate